# Terminate compound statements in IPython

Tags: python, for-loop, ipython, python-interactive

I am new to python (and programming), so please forgive me if I don't follow the correct nomenclature. It makes finding answers to even the most trivial questions hard. Thanks!

In IPython I typed the following:

```
for i in s:
    print([s:i]
```

The white space was added by IPython automatically.

Hitting `return` twice does not get me back to the iPython prompt, however. In other words I cannot end the compound statement.

What do I need to do?

Many thanks!

Comment: Try to hit return more than twice. Also maybe you're leaving a parenthesis or a square bracket opened. Besides your expression `[s:i]` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Paulo, thank you! Yes, I did not close the parenthesis. Can you imagine, I did not see this at all, even after staring at the screen for minutes to find a mistake!!!

Comment: That has happened to me numerous times :) Glad you could fix it.